# I can't get the input from OptionMenu in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a simple code, where the user selects an option from the OptionMenu, then this option gets print, when I use .get() I get the error
`AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'get'`

Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printtxt():
    x = menu.get()
    print(x)

menu_txt = StringVar(root)
menu_txt.set('Text')

texts = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Yellow']

menu = OptionMenu(root, menu_txt, *texts)
menu.pack()

bttn = Button(root, text='Submit', command=printtxt)
bttn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to call `.get()` on the associated Var (`menu_txt` in your case), rather than the OptionMenu itself.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `get()` on the associated variable, not the widget itself.

```
def printtxt():
    x = menu_txt.get()
    print(x)
```

Comment: I wrote it in the code above inside the function and I got the error

Comment: @TheDiamondCreeper I guarantee this works in the code example in the question.

Comment: Where do I put it?